# some issue with using/not using 'var' in javascript

Tags: javascript

books.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <datas>
    <book>
      <id>
        1
      </id>
      <title>
        PHP Enterprise
      </title>
      <author>
        Wiwit
      </author>   
    </book>
    <book>
      <id>
        2
      </id>
      <title>
        PHP Undercover
      </title>
      <author>
        Wiwit
      </author>       
    </book>
  </datas>
```

test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax Client</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
// creates XMLHttpRequest Instance
function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){

  // will store XMLHttpRequest object
  // at here
  var xmlHttp;

  // works all exceprt IE6 and older  
  try
  {

    // try to create XMLHttpRequest object
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    // assume IE 6 or older
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e){ }
  }

  // return object or display error
  if (!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest Object");
  else
    return xmlHttp;
}

function process()
{
  if(xmlHttp)
  {
    try
    {
      xmlHttp.open("Get","books.xml", true);
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      alert("Can't connect to server\n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}

function handleRequestStateChange()
{
  myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivElement");

  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1)
  {
    myDiv.innerHTML += "Request status: 1 (loading) <br/>";
  }
  else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 2)
  {
    myDiv.innerHTML += "Request status: 2 (loaded) <br/>";
  }
  else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 3)
  {
    myDiv.innerHTML += "Request status: 3 (interactive) <br/>"; 
  }
  else if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
  {
    if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
      try
      {
        handleXMLData();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Problem retrieving data:\n" + xmlHttp.statusText);
    }


  }

}

function handleXMLData()
{
  var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;

   xmlRoot = xmlResponse.documentElement;

  idArray = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("id");  
  titleArray = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("title");
  authorArray = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("author");   

  var html = "";

  for( var i=0; i<titleArray.length; i++)
  {
    html += idArray.item(i).firstChild.data + ", " + titleArray.item(i).firstChild.data +  ", " + authorArray.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";
  }
  myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivElement");
  myDiv.innerHTML += "Server says: <br/>" + html;  
}
console.log(xmlRoot); 
</script>
</head>

<body onload="process()">
Our collections:
<div id="myDivElement" />
</body>
</html>
```

Above code is taken from: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/AJAX-Client-Side-Processing-XML-Data-use-XMLHttpRequest-P356.html

In this function `function handleXMLData()`, some places use `var` such as `var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;`, some places did not use `var`, such as: `xmlRoot = xmlResponse.documentElement;` so my question is:

1. why not put `var` in front of  `xmlRoot`?
2. usually inside function(){}, if we do not put var in front of variable, it will be global variable, such as:

   function test()
   { gar = '9';}
   test();
   console.log(gar);

But when I put `console.log(xmlRoot);` just before tag `</script>`, in chrome console, it shows:Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlRoot is not defined, why? Is not `xmlRoot` a global variable since there is no `var` in front of it?

Comment: Anything that depends on the remote data being read into the browser should be executed by the response handler.  The response handler could even call extra functions that you write, if that is useful.  Otherwise, code is likely to run too soon and the data won't exist.

Comment: Im pretty sure that if you write `setTimeout(function(){console.log(xmlRoot)}, 10000); ` xmlRoot will be defined. The magic of asynchronous call!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I hope you're just suggesting that as a quick test.  You should generally use a callback rather than waiting for an arbitrary amount of time for something to happen.

Comment: @jahroy im saying the glabal var will be declared after the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `var` may not have used here because the author wants the variable to be a global one
2. It is throwing the error because when `console.log(xmlRoot);`, the execution context is unaware about `xmlRoot` since `handleXMLData` may not have executed yet (because it a used in the callback function to an asynchronous call)

Answer (score 0):

`xmlRoot` will be a global variable if it has been defined. If the function that refers to it has not been called, `xmlRoot` won't be defined.

You tested `xmlRoot` just before the script exits, i.e. during the first execution of the code, before `handleXMLData()` had been called.